# Is there a cross-architecture way to detect CPU features on linux?

Tags: c, linux, cpu, simd

Is there any way to determine CPU features in a cross-architecture (i.e. works similarly on ARM, x86, etc.) way on Linux? `/proc/cpuinfo` would fit as a solution, but it seems that it isn't meant to be parsed as there is a number of inconsistencies. For example, the field I'm interested in is named `flags` on x86, but `Features` on ARM and so on. Is there another standard way to get the equivalent information?

Comment: What if a CPU *has* no features? "Cross-platform" is a high demand.

Comment: No features is also an answer :-) As for cross-platform, `/proc/cpuinfo` already meets my definition of cross-platform, I'm just unsure about backwards-compatibility guarantees.

Comment: The `/proc/cpuinfo` interface will always remain consistent for each architecture. In kernel dev land, the number one rule is to never break userland programs.

Comment: CPU features are architecture specific, so what is the point of a cross architecture solution anyway?

Comment: @tangrs `/proc/cpuinfo` is not a documented interface. I would suggest `/proc/self/auxv` as a more stable and documented alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `lscpu --parse` ?

Comment: I'd like not to call external programs

Comment: `lscpu` gets the info from [/proc/cpuinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may use open source [Yeppp! library](http://www.yeppp.info) (disclosure: I am the author) which provides information on CPU features on x86, ARM, MIPS, and PowerPC.

[This example](http://docs.yeppp.info/c/_cpu_info_8c-example.html) hints how to retrieve this information with Yeppp!